# Mod Rewrite beautify link

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have this project and I have products list retriever from database.
So when i try to GET them to show in my web i end up with links like this

```
http://localhost/myDomain.net/randomFolder/ad.php?title=theTitle&id=1
```

and what I need is this

```
http://localhost//myDomain.net/radomFolder/theTitle/1.html
```

I tried to place this into .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/myDomain\.net/randomFolder/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$
/myDomain.net/randomFilder/ad.php?title=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

With this writen code bearly reacts, actually I think it's  not working at all, so I beleive that I need some kind of htaccess configuration, but i have no idea what kind of config is needed or I should change my script.
I have tried to place htaccess file in other folders, but I it simply does not work.

Comment: Is your .htaccess located in `/myDomain.net/` folder or a level above it?

Comment: Yes, .htaccess is located at /myDomain.net/folder

Answer (score 0):

Place this rule in `/myDomain.net/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myDomain.net/

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.html$ $1/ad.php?title=$2&id=$3 [L,NC,QSA,R]
```

Comment: It reacts the same.. some why it simply does no influence.

Comment: Is `http://localhost//myDomain.net/radomFolder/theTitle/1.html` causing 404? Are there more rules in `/myDomain.net/.htaccess`?

Comment: yea it is 404, there is not a single line more then you wrote. I tested a lot of different methods of rewrite and none of then actually do the job, I would think that my server does not have something that is needed, but yes it's XAMPP so he has Apache if i miss type something error is thrown, but if I do some valid code it just ignores it... that drives me crazy

Comment: ok first verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: Ok where is `ad.php` located?

Comment: myDomain.net/randomFolder/ad.php

Comment: ok enter: `http://localhost//myDomain.net/randomFolder/theTitle/1.html` in your browser. (You had it as **`radomFolder`**) If you get 404 then try: `http://localhost//myDomain.net/randomFolder/ad.php?title=theTitle&id=1`)

Comment: theTitle variable here is text that is used as title inside of the files at randomFolder not file names it self I need to make titles as link name for SEO purpose,so yes first link with all / returned 404 and second one works like a charm

Comment: Do you have `/myDomain.net/randomFolder/.htaccess` as well?

Comment: definitely... yes there is no extra .htaccess